# Create a list of numbers that exist in a file with Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a file with a list of words and numbers. What I want to do is create a list of numbers between 0 and  that are not contained within this file.

I have tried to the following to no avail:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

PATH_TO_FILE = "C:\\Path\\To\\My\\File"

file = open( PATH_TO_FILE, "r")

open_numbers = list(range(0,10500))
used_numbers = []
for lines in file.readlines():
    lines = lines.replace(',', '')

    number = [int(s) for s in lines.split() if s.isdigit()]
    print number
    if number in open_numbers:
        open_numbers.remove(number)
        print lines
        print number

print open_numbers
```

My list just contains the max range without removing the numbers

The file is a list of macros for a C file. The parameters use a unique value, and I want to find out which values I can still use
Sample Data:

```
MACRO(PARAM1, PARAM2, VALUE, PARAM) //ie MACRO(somefunc, "string id", 200, "string")
...(20k file)
```

Comment: It would help if you give an example of 1 or 2 lines of your data

Comment: sample I/O will explain the problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number = [int(s) for s in lines.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

produces a LIST of numbers... [2, 7, 8] for example.
open_numbers.remove(number) is trying to remove a list from your list, which is not the expected impact.  Instead

```
numbers = [int(s) for s in lines.split() if s.isdigit()]
for number in numbers:
    if number in open_numbers: ...
```

Comment: Looking at your edit... MACRO(PARAM1, PARAM2, VALUE) //ie MACRO(somefunc, "string id", 200) would not expand to any integer numbers.  The last part would be '200)' which can't be translated.  You'll need something more involved to pick out that value...

Comment: Thankfully, there is always a 4th parameter, which is why I stripped out the commas in order to get the numbers. It doesn't need to be perfect, it's just a quick/dirty tool that should help us manage these IDs